# How do I define a helper method in my Rails module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, methods, module, helper

I’m using Rails 4.2.4.  How do I define a helper (private) method within a module?  I have this module

```
module WebpageHelper

  def get_url(url)
    content = get_content(url)
    ..
  end

  def get_content(url)
    …
  end

  module_function :get_url

end
```

I don’t want the method “get_content” to be publicly accessible, but with the above code I get the error

```
Error during processing: undefined method `get_content' for WebpageHelper:Module
```

How do i properly define a private helper method in my module?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way (and mostly how existing libs are written) do this by making a class within the module that deals with all the logic, and the module just provides a convenient method.

Docs here;

[Private method](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/private)

Or see [Here](http://6ftdan.com/allyourdev/2015/05/02/private-module-methods-in-ruby/) for some nice examples e.g. `class << self` option.

Comment: I need a code example here, because if I'm reading you right, you're saying create a class with the helper method, which would make this method publicly accessible, which is exactly what I'm tryihng to avoid.  This method will only be used exclusively in this module.

Comment: So the method of this inner class can only be accessed within the module itself?